# convert "JSON data to textview" to "JSON data to listview"

Tags: android, listview, twitter, textview

Hello i have a working code that displays a twitter timeline into a textview:

```
    void examineJSONdata()
{
    TextView tvData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    try
    {
        String x = "";
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);
        byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
        String jsontext = new String(buffer);
        JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);

        x = "JSON parsed.\nThere are [" + entries.length() + "]\n\n";

        int i;
        for (i=0;i<entries.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject post = entries.getJSONObject(i);
            x += "------------\n";
            x += "Date:" + post.getString("created_at") + "\n";
            x += "Post:" + post.getString("text") + "\n\n";
        }
        tvData.setText(x);
    }
    catch (Exception je)
    {
        tvData.setText("Error w/file: " + je.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now i want to try a ListView instead of a TextView

I have found a code on StackOverFlow [Android App: JSON array from web to listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164963/android-app-json-array-from-web-to-listview)

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(...);
String json = "[\"Country1\",\"Country2\",\"Country3\"]";
try {
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();

        String[] stringarray = new String[array.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            stringarray[i] = array.getString(i);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringarray); 
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
} catch (JSONException e) {
        // handle JSON parsing exceptions...
}
```

I have tried to do this but I can't get i work
Would someone help convert the code with me? I think all the neccessary info is in the first code.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Isn't the listview showing or is it empty or is it showing wrong data?

Comment: what it is showing? any `Error`? Any `Crash` ?

Comment: The first code is working but instead i want to use a Listview so i found the second code in another StackOverFlow question and i want to use it do display my data and not that country etc. So i thought if someone could help me to reformat the code in the second one so i have a listview instead of a TextView.

Comment: I do not understand you completely but I think replacing `JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();` with `String x = "";
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);
        byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
        String jsontext = new String(buffer);
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsontext);` whold solve your problem

Comment: Cant see anything wrong with the second one..are you setting contentView to your listview?

Comment: M Mohsin Naeem i think you understand me but i doesn't working

Comment: Hasslarn: The first code is my code and is working fine but it's using a TextView and I want to use a ListView so I use the second code as template (it is not mine).

Comment: It is giving `error` or showing nothing? Are you add `listView` in your `xml` file?

Comment: it just show me the whole json file (a large text file with all settings)

Comment: :( btw it is not the way you are asking question here. Any how I post a answer according to your `so called problem.` Your problem is `How to parse a JsonArray` as `String Array`.

Comment: Srry im just starting to developing an im just 16 and i dont know what it was or how i should question it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String x = "";
    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);
    byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
    while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
    String jsontext = new String(buffer);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsontext);
    String[] stringarray = new String[array.length()];
```

and

```
int i;
    for (i=0;i<array.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject post = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String temp;

        temp += "Date:" + post.getString("created_at") + "\n";
        temp += "Post:" + post.getString("text");
        stringarray[i]=temp;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringarray); 
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working i only changed String temp; to String temp = ""; so it's working but i also like, cause the whole tweet is displaying, to display only as long as 1 rule is. So you do not see the whole tweet just a part and when you click at it it shows the whole tweet.